# "Welcome to TeX.SX!" might be misleading as such a website doesn't exist

Tags: discussion, comments, new-users, publicity, acronyms

The often seen "Welcome to TeX.SX!" message for new users may look like a URL to someone and therefore get used in such a manner ("hey checkout TeX.SX, it's cool"), but the website called tex.sx is not accessible.

This is not a big issue, but it somewhat irks me that this common abbreviation doesn't also function as a forward to the real website (see youtu.be and the like) and therefore might create problems.

Any thoughts?

Comment: There are various ways or representing the name of the site: I favour `TeX-sx`, but cross-network it is more common to have `TeX.SE` :-)

Comment: Related or duplicate http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/3372/which-is-more-common-tex-se-or-tex-sx or better http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/2287/change-tex-latex-stack-exchange-to-tex-stack-exchange In case of confusion use a dash is sufficient.

Comment: This has been irritating to me personally for years, but I've long since given up on convincing 100-odd sites to change their ways. In good news, I've rarely if ever heard a report of anyone ever actually being seriously confused by the shorthand.

Answer (score 15):

I don't consider this an issue, since people who see that message are already on this site. The suggestion is not "Go to TeX.SX" or "Visit TeX.SX".

As an aside: For those posting

> Welcome to TeX.SX!

verbatim as a comment, they could consider changing this to

> Welcome to TeX.SE!

as the `.SE` suffix is more commonly used to represent the Stack Exchange network. Moreover, this is also supported by the use of network-wide [magic-links](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/94000/168244). That is, consider writing `Welcome to [tex.se]!` instead - you save a couple of keystrokes - since `[tex.se]` will be converted to display

> Welcome to [TeX - LaTeX](http://tex.stackexchange.com)!

Comment: How does that save keystrokes? You don't need shift for `T` or `X`, but you have to add `[` and `]`. Not suggesting it isn't a good idea for other reasons. Just grumbling about false advertising ;).

Comment: @cfr: You need 9 (or 10) key strokes for `TeX.SX` (it includes Shifts), but only 8 for `[tex.se]`.

Comment: Not if you use caps lock the second time: shift-T - e - caps lock - X - . - S - X. (Although you need one more to release caps lock and you need not to have turned your caps lock key into another ctrl or an altgr or something similar.)

Comment: @cfr: Nope. Once you use CAPS LOCK, YOU CAN'T TURN IT OFF. THAT'S HOW IT WORKS... ;)

Comment: That's what I said! However, it is no more key strokes to type the thing. You just need a ninth if you want to type anything in lower-case later. But that's merely an unintended side-effect... :). (Doctrine of double effect and all that.)

Comment: not on my machine!

Comment: You guys seriously discussed the optimisation of a single keystroke with 6 comments? :D Am I seriously adding a 7th to this? At least I know where to find perfectionists! ;)